# -ms-transform is not working in ie8 where as working for all other browsers

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

`-ms-transform: translateY(-50%);` is not working in IE8 where as working for chrome, firefox and ie8+ browsers. How can this make to work for ie8 ?

Comment: How do you make it work? In IE 8, javascript or jQuery.

Answer (score 4):

IE 8 is only CSS 2.1 compatible and `-ms-transform` is a CSS 3 feature implemented in IE 9 and 10 so don't expect it to work.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh781508%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Windows Internet Explorer 8 is fully compliant with the Cascading
>   Style Sheets, Level 2 Revision 1 (CSS2.1) specification and supports
>   ***some*** features of Cascading Style Sheets, Level 3 (CSS3).

(emphasis mine)

It supports *some* and not all.

Comment: Thank you amit . But is there any other way to work this property in ie8 or apply this style ?

Comment: No, I don't think so @user3686276

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can use the Matrix Filters (-ms-filter) to target IE8

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533014%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You will have to use a tool like this one to convert your transform to a filter

http://www.useragentman.com/IETransformsTranslator/

For example, in your case the result would be

```
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";
```